# How to update a notification while is visible adding new info?

Tags: android, notifications

My application receives messages from GCM.

I have configured a service and a broadcastreceiver correctly. Then, when a message is comming, I show a notification. I have differents notifications for different kind of messages. This runs fine.

Well, now I need to update the notification when a new message is received, such as Whatsapp.

For example, when Whatsapp receives one message from a contact, shows text message, "Hello world!" but when receive another one from same contact, changes the information on notification, showing "Two new messages". If receive message from other contact, notification shows "3 messages on 2 chats" and something like that.

I need to do the same with two type of messages but not all. Then, I need to know which notifications are showing the actionBar and then update ones and no others. I would like to create a bucle for all notifications showed, analyze them and check if there are anyone showed yet of my specific type, previously to create new one.

How can I get info from the notificationManager or StatusActionBar in order to change it? How can I check if the notification showed on Actionbar has the same type of notification comming?

Thanks.

GCMIntentService.java

This service analyze an "extra" value from GCM Message (notificationType). Make a switch case and composes data for show in notification.

Has a method to show the notification. I have put some comments on showNotification method for understad what I need.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private SQLiteDatabase localDB;

private SharedPreferences localSettings;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(StaticValues.GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int gcmNotificationType;
    String gcmMess;
    long gcmUserIDFrom;
    long gcmUserIDTo;
    String gcmUserFromCode;
    String gcmEventShortDescription;

    boolean showNotification = false;

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {                        

            // Hay notificaciones de varios tipos así que las catalogamos y hacemos cosas diferentes en función del tipo
            // Hay que recuperar los settings para saber qué notificaciones se tratan y cuáles no.

            if (extras.getString("notificationType") != null) {

                gcmNotificationType = Integer.valueOf(extras.getString("notificationType"));
                gcmMess = extras.getString("message");
                gcmEventShortDescription = extras.getString("eventShortDescription");
                gcmUserFromCode = getString(R.string.app_name);

                Log.d(TAG, "NotificationType: " + gcmNotificationType);

                localSettings = getSharedPreferences(StaticValues.PREFS, 0);

                switch (gcmNotificationType) {

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_SINGLE:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Message received from " + extras.getString("userFromCode"));

                        localDB = PassObjects.getLocalDB();

                        gcmUserFromCode = extras.getString("userFromCode");
                        gcmUserIDFrom = Long.valueOf(extras.getString("userIDFrom"));
                        gcmUserIDTo = Long.valueOf(extras.getString("userIDTo"));

                        String inDate;
                        inDate = FormatValidators.convertTimeStampToString();

                        GenericMessageMethods.addMessages(gcmUserIDFrom, gcmUserIDTo, gcmMess, inDate, getApplicationContext(), localDB, false);

                        // Sólo llamo a la cola de broadcast de la pantalla 
                        // si el mensaje es para el perfil en uso

                        if (gcmUserIDTo == PassObjects.getLOG_INFO_LAST_USER_ID()) {

                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent("com.example.JourneyApp.journeyActivities.LocalMessagesActivity");
                            chatIntent.putExtra("userIDFrom",extras.getString("userIDFrom"));
                            chatIntent.putExtra("userIDTo", extras.getString("userIDTo"));
                            chatIntent.putExtra("message", extras.getString("message"));
                            chatIntent.putExtra("messageDate", inDate);

                            sendBroadcast(chatIntent);
                        }

                        if (localSettings.getBoolean("TMP_NOTIFY_MESSAGES_FLAG",true)) {

                            if (localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_MESSAGES_FLAG",true)) {

                                showNotification = true;

                            } else {

                                Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "MessagesFlag: " + localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_MESSAGES_FLAG",true));
                            }
                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications TEMPORALLY desactivated. " +
                                    " Processing messages with LocalMessagesActivity running");
                        }

                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_ON_EVENT_ALL_ON_LINE:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Message received on event " + gcmEventShortDescription + " from " + extras.getString("userFromCode"));

                        gcmUserFromCode = extras.getString("userFromCode") + " " + getString(R.string.GCM_ON_EVENT) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;

                        Intent foroIntent = new Intent("com.example.JourneyApp.journeyActivities.ForoMessagesActivity");

                        foroIntent.putExtra("userIDFrom",extras.getString("userIDFrom"));
                        foroIntent.putExtra("eventID", extras.getString("eventID"));
                        foroIntent.putExtra("message", extras.getString("message"));
                        foroIntent.putExtra("userFromCode", extras.getString("userFromCode"));

                        sendBroadcast(foroIntent);

                        if (localSettings.getBoolean("TMP_NOTIFY_EVENT_MESSAGES_FLAG",true)) {

                            if (localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_MESSAGES_FLAG",true)) {

                                showNotification = true;

                            } else {

                                Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                        + "EventMessagesFlag: " + localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_MESSAGES_FLAG",true));
                            }

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications TEMPORALLY desactivated: " +
                                    " Processing messages with ForoMessagesActivity running");

                        }
                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_NEW_EVENT:

                        Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.GCM_new_event_created) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        if (localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_EVENTS_TYPE_ID",StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) != StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_NEVER) {

                            if (localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_EVENTS_TYPE_ID",StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) == StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ONLY_MY_INTEREST) {

                                if (PassObjects.getLOG_INFO_LAST_USER_ID() > 0) {

                                    ArrayList<Integer> arrayLikesProfileLogged = PassObjects.getLOG_INFO_USER_LIKES();
                                    ArrayList<Integer> arrayLikesOnEvent = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                                    // Los extras están en String. Lo paso a un String[], lo recorro, parseo a int 
                                    // y añado al array. Recorro el del evento y en cuanto encuentro uno coincidente,
                                    // salgo y muestro notificación

                                    String extrasEventLikesString = extras.getString("eventLikes");

                                    Log.d(TAG, "EventLikes: (string) " + extrasEventLikesString);

                                    String[] auxS = extrasEventLikesString.replace(" ", "").split(",");

                                    for (int i = 0; i < auxS.length; i++) {

                                        arrayLikesOnEvent.add(Integer.parseInt(auxS[i]));

                                    }

                                    Log.d(TAG, "EventLikes: (ArrayList<Integer>) " + arrayLikesOnEvent.toString());

                                    for (int x:arrayLikesOnEvent) {

                                        if (arrayLikesProfileLogged.contains(x)) {

                                            gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_new_event_created);
                                            showNotification = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification is: " + localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_EVENTS_TYPE_ID",StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) + " but user not logged");

                                }

                            } else {

                                gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_new_event_created);
                                showNotification = true;

                            }

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "Notify new events type: " + localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_EVENTS_TYPE_ID", StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) );

                        }
                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_NEW_USER:

                        Log.d(TAG, "New user created: " + extras.getString("userFromCode"));

                        if (localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_USERS_TYPE_ID", StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) != StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_NEVER) {

                            if (localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_USERS_TYPE_ID", StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) == StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ONLY_MY_INTEREST) {

                                if (PassObjects.getLOG_INFO_LAST_USER_ID() > 0) {

                                    ArrayList<Integer> arrayLikesProfileLogged = PassObjects.getLOG_INFO_USER_LIKES();
                                    ArrayList<Integer> arrayLikesOnUser = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                                    // Los extras están en String. Lo paso a un String[], lo recorro, parseo a int 
                                    // y añado al array. Recorro el del evento y en cuanto encuentro uno coincidente,
                                    // salgo y muestro notificación

                                    String extrasUserLikesString = extras.getString("userLikes");

                                    Log.d(TAG, "UserLikes: (string) " + extrasUserLikesString);

                                    String[] auxS = extrasUserLikesString.replace(" ", "").split(",");

                                    for (int i = 0; i < auxS.length; i++) {

                                        arrayLikesOnUser.add(Integer.parseInt(auxS[i]));

                                    }

                                    Log.d(TAG, "UserLikes: (ArrayList<Integer>): " + arrayLikesOnUser.toString());

                                    for (int x:arrayLikesOnUser) {

                                        if (arrayLikesProfileLogged.contains(x)) {

                                            gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_profile_created_part1);
                                            showNotification = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                } else {

                                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification is: " + localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_USERS_TYPE_ID", StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) + " but user not logged");

                                }

                            } else {

                                gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_profile_created_part1);
                                showNotification = true;

                            }

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "Notify new uers type: " + localSettings.getInt("NOTIFY_NEW_USERS_TYPE_ID", StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_ALWAYS) );

                        }
                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_CHANGE_EVENT:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Changes on event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        gcmMess = getString(R.string.GCM_changes_on_event) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;
                        showNotification = true;

                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_LINK_EVENT:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Linked user from event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        if (localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_LINK_FLAG", true)) {

                            gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_linked) + " " + getString(R.string.GCM_ON_EVENT) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;
                            showNotification = true;

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "Notify link event: " + localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_LINK_FLAG", true) );

                        }
                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_UNLINK_EVENT:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Unlinked user from event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        if (localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_UNLINK_FLAG", true)) {

                            gcmMess = getString(R.string.mess_unlinked) + " " + getString(R.string.GCM_ON_EVENT) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;
                            showNotification = true;

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "Notify unlink event: " + localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_UNLINK_FLAG", true) );

                        }
                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_EVENT_CAPACITY_FULL:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Capacity full on event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        if (localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_CAPACITY_FULL_FLAG", true)) {

                            gcmMess = getString(R.string.GCM_event_capacity_completed) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;
                            showNotification = true;

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifications desactivated: "
                                    + "Notify event capacity full: " + localSettings.getBoolean("NOTIFY_EVENT_CAPACITY_FULL_FLAG", true));
                        }

                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_EVENT_WILL_BEGIN_AT:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Begin notification on event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        gcmMess = getString(R.string.GCM_event_will_begin_part_1) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription + " " + getString(R.string.GCM_event_will_begin_part_2);
                        showNotification = true;

                        break;

                    case StaticValues.NOTIFICATION_EVENT_CANCELLED:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Cancel event: " + gcmEventShortDescription);

                        gcmMess = getString(R.string.GCM_event_canceled) + " " + gcmEventShortDescription;
                        showNotification = true;

                        break;

                    default:

                        Log.d(TAG, "Notification not in case");

                        break;


                }       //END Switch

                if (showNotification) {

                    showNotification(gcmNotificationType, gcmMess, gcmUserFromCode);
                }

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Cannot find <notificationType> label on extras");
                Log.d(TAG, "Extras.size(): " + extras.size() + ", extrasToString " + extras.toString());

            }

        } else {

            Log.d(TAG, "Other GCM message type received");
        }

    } else {

        Log.d(TAG, "Extras are empty");
    }    

    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void showNotification(int nType, String mMessage, String mTitle) {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             // I would like to analyze ActionBar data or NotificationManager data
             // Something like...

             // for (x:CurrentVisibleNotifications) {          // Which will be this object?

             //        int currentId = x.getId();
             //        int currentNumber = x.getNumber();        // This is a property of notification

             //        if (currentId == nType) {

             //            mMessage = currentNumber++ + " new messages";

             //        }

             //   }


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)                

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.journey_icon_orange)                
        .setContentTitle(mTitle)                
        .setContentText(mMessage)
        .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        ;

    // Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);     
    // PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notIntent, 0);         
    // mBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);         
    mNotificationManager.notify(nType, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For update a view when your app receive the PushNotification you need  LocalBroadCastManager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

In the Service "GCMIntentService", in the method onMessage you need add the nextCode:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Reload");
        // You can also include some extra data.
        intent.putExtra("message", "Reload");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Whit this you register a new Broadcasting message.

Now in the class for update you need add the next:
in the onCreate method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter("Reload"));
```

and before you need add next methods:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Reload")) {
            //Actions...for reload a listView, TextView, etc...

        }
    }
};
```

And important add the onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

.... PD: Sorry for my English...